# How can I safely remove desktop environments from Ubuntu Studio login screen?

Tags: gnome, xfce, desktop-environments, cinnamon, ubuntu-studio

I have been using Ubuntu Studio several years now. Seem to have a bunch of redundant offerings for apps, etc. listed as installed. While I have logged onto the Xfce interface for emergency Cinnamon failure, I'm happy with just the latest Ubuntu Studio and the latest Cinnamon.

So the logon screen seems to have too many offerings and I think some can go as I don't know what they are and never use them. With that said, I would like to safely remove Xfce also because of all the duplicate menu entries for Users, etc. in my Cinnamon interface. The current list I can log onto is as follows:

- Cinnamon
- Cinnamon (Software Rendering)
- GNOME
- GNOME on Xorg
- GNOME on Xorg
- Ubuntu
- Ubuntu on Wayland
- Xfce Session

Any advice on what and how I can safely remove anything I don't need from that list while keeping Ubuntu Studio Cinnamon would be appreciated. Thinking Synaptic might be the best tool. Eager to clean things up but don't want to break my existing system.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! *Why* do you have so many options in the first place? How did you install the other non-default environments? Please **[edit]** your question and clarify.

Comment: AFAIK the above DEs has nothing in common except ```gnome-terminal``` which is used by **Cinnamon** and also some other gnome software like **system monitor**.You can safely remove those desktop environments and some of the related packages via ```sudo apt-get remove xfce4* gnome-shell* gnome-session*```.If I'm wrong please someone chime in and correct that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know the desktop environments you mentioned has nothing in common except some gnome software like **gnome-terminal** and **gnome-system-monitor** which is used by **Cinnamon**.So for example I think it's completely safe to remove **Xfce4** and its window manager and also some unneeded gnome software like **gnome-shell** and **gnome-session** :

```
sudo apt-get remove xfce4* xfwm4* gnome-shell* gnome-session*
```

Note that `gnome-session*` includes `gnome-session-wayland` too,so your gnome on wayland(aka **Ubuntu on Wayland**) would get deleted too.The same with `gnome-shell*`.

Another option is to delete the package `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` but it might result in removing some programs that you might want , for instance `libre-office` or `gnome-mines`, etc.

I think those are enough to delete the unnecessary packages and DEs and at the same time to prevent your system from breaking.But it might not be a 100% cleanup.

Comment: The top command worked. Seems a utility app or two disappeared but easily replaced. Thanks for answering my question so thoroughly, @ParsaMousavi.